# Database in firestore suddenly deleted

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I recently implemented a new feature and was testing my application locally. However, I encountered an issue where I couldn't receive any feedback from requests made to my existing Firestore database. Upon entering the Firebase project and accessing Firestore, I discovered that the database and all its existing documents and records were no longer visible.

This problem is negatively impacting the users of my system, as they can only authenticate but are unable to benefit from any other functionality due to the inability to manipulate the data in Firestore. Moreover, it's also hindering the progress of my project, as I am unable to test new features in this state.

In this regard, I am seeking the expertise of those familiar with this topic to help me understand why the database in Firestore was deleted. Additionally, I am very eager to know if there is a possibility of recovering the database along with all its documents and records. Losing this data is not an option, and its recovery is of utmost importance.

I've tried contacting Google, but haven't gotten any feedback yet.

**Code Snippet Used:**

*firebase.service.ts*

```
async getCustomerProjects(customerId) {
    const querySnapshot = await this.db
      .collection("projects", (ref) =>
        ref.where("customer", "==", customerId)
      )
      .get()
      .toPromise();

    const projects = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const project: any = doc.data();
      project.id = doc.id;
      projects.push(project);
    });

    return projects;
  }
```

*integration.component.ts*

```
this.customerSubscription = this._storageService
      .getSelectedCustomer()
      .subscribe(async (customer) => {
        this.selectedCustomer = customer;
        if (customer) {
          const customerProjects = await this.firebaseService.getCustomerProjects(customer.id);
          this.showContent = false;
          if (customerProjects.length > 0) {
            this.showSelectProject = true;
            this.showCustomerHasNoProject = false;
            this.showProjectHasNoCampaign = false;
          } else {
            this.showSelectProject = false;
            this.showCustomerHasNoProject = true;
            this.showProjectHasNoCampaign = false;
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Was it actually deleted or is it just not visible?  Secondly, you must of ran some sort of code just before this happened?  Post that code so we can start to guess how this is possible.  Did you run any sort of DELETE command and perhaps forgot to add the WHERE statement?  Granted, that would still have a database existing, just empty.  But we need a little more information for someone on this site to help.

Comment: It's impossible for us to know why any data is deleted without first understanding what you're actively doing with it.  Firestore documents don't just "suddenly" disappear.  It gets deleted only because some code or API caused it to happen.

Comment: @easleyfixed I haven't deleted anything from the database. I didn't use any delete operation either. My actions were solely focused on retrieving data from the database.

Comment: I'll add snippets of code that I used.

Comment: Also question, is this in a dev build (no public internet access) or does it have web access to randos ?  Just checking to make sure someone didn't sneak a "; DROP TABLE" into one of your forms that didn't get validated?

Comment: Why do you say DROP TABLE? Firestore is non-relational.

Comment: I guess I should of said it was an example scenario where it could happen, but point is, if you give users access to the data, maybe they did something to it ?  But if no one but you has access to this, then it has to be the last code that was used.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore/Firebase will never automatically delete your database. It's not a thing.

More likely causes/things you should investigate:

- The user deleted the documents in the app without intending to.
- You (or a collaborator on the project) deleted the documents or collection from the console.
- You made a mistake in the code, which deleted the documents.

There used to not be (and for your current situation probably still isn't) any way to recover such deleted data. **But** Firestore just launched [Point in Time Recovery (PiTR)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pitr) in preview, which (once configured) keeps backup copies of any documents that are written/deleted - and which you can then restore up to a week.

Note that all of these only apply to the data in the database, not to the database itself. The only thing I can think of there is that your database got into a broken/flagged state somehow, but you should either see some indication of that in the console - or get error messages in the network tab of your browser.